# How can I recover a password from a sftp bookmark in pantheon-files?

Tags: pantheon-files, security, ssh, keyring

A while ago I was working with a remote environment and I decided to bookmark it in **Pantheon-Files app.** **I inserted my username and password and I marked the "Keep it forever" box** so I don't have to introduce it again.

The problem: **I have forgotten the password** and I need it so badly now.

Is there anyway to discover what was my password? Since the sftp connection works **I guess it must be stored somewhere.** But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is stored in your login keyring.
The easiest way to find it is with [GNOME Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse).

1. Install Seahorse from AppCenter.

[image: Seahorse in AppCenter]

2. Open the application from AppCenter or open the *Passwords and Keys* application from the *Applications Menu*.

[image: Seahorse Application Window]

3. Click the *Login* bookmark on the left under *Passwords*.
4. Find your login which should be marked as a *Network password*.

[image: Seahorse Login Keys List]

5. Right click the entry and select properties.

[image: Seahorse SSH Key Properties Dialog]

6. From the properties dialog, expand the password field.

[image: Seahorse SSH Key Properties Dialog Expanded Password]

7. Check the box *Show password* to reveal your password.

[image: Seahorse SSH Key Properties Dialog Show Password]

Comment: Wow!! It worked!! The password was there all this time!! Thank you so much for the answer, it was a nice mini- tutorial!